# ssh connection "permission denied" message

Tags: ssh, connection

When I execute the command `ssh localhost` (in Ubuntu 10.10), it will display the error message "permission denied(public key)."
What may be the problem?

Is there any problem in `sshd_config file in /etc/ssh`?  Should `PasswordAuthentication` be set to `no`?  I have set the `PasswordAuthentication` to `no`, but still it gives me the error "permission denied(publickey)."

Comment: Did you disable password authentication in `sshd_config`? Why? What you are trying to do with this?

Comment: Can you include the output of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? Use pastebin (pastebin.ubuntu.com) and take out any sensitive information

Answer (score 5):

you need to set file permissions right ,
try this ..

```
 $chmod go-w ~/
 $chmod 700 ~/.ssh
 $chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: @Volution2111Volution2111:thanks ya.. its worked fine now, I hv set the permissions..

Comment: @Statwonk, what?  His answer is completely valid, an incorrect permission is going to cause ssh keys to fail automatically, and the ~/.ssh is the default home directory that ssh keys are stored to on almost all *nix distros.

Comment: @MichaelRyanSoileau you're right, I don't remember making this comment, but it clearly looked wrong (removed it). Thanks for raising it to me!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@host
```

Or since you are on localhost try copying your ssh key (rsa or dsa) inside the file  `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

For key authentication in ssh, you need to authorize your keys on host first AFAIK.

Comment: hey still it does not work ya.. what is the problem do u kw??

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've installed "openssh-server" because it's not installed by default.

sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Comment: If it was not installed, OP would not get an error message at all, but hang.

Comment: @Lekensteyn You would normally think that .. but NO. *It does not just hang.*