# SSH "Permission Denied (Public Key)" Automatically re-occuring problem

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, authentication

I have a headless server with (until recently) working SSH and public key auth. I deactivated passwords and had a problem resembling the one in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37051/ssh-connection-permission-denied-message), ie. upon SSH-ing into my server I get: `Permission denied (publickey).`

[Ratnakar Pawar](https://askubuntu.com/users/14316/ratnakar-pawar) helpfully suggested:

```
 $chmod go-w ~/
 $chmod 700 ~/.ssh
 $chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Which solved both [priyaudupi's](https://askubuntu.com/users/15008/priyaudupi) issue and - for a time - mine. However now this issue seems to automatically reset on a 24-48 hour basis, I have changed the authorisation correctly twice (plugging in my keyboard and *very carefully* blind typing commands. This gives me normal passwordless, public auth ssh from the single authorised computer... then fails again within 48 hours.

What might be causing this, I can't think of anything that would be able to automatically change permissions on my folders either... any suggestions?

**Update 2nd May 2014**

I have checked`crontab -l` for both the root and user, I have nothing on my user. The only cron task on root is one that updates my DNS server. It does so more regularly than the problem re-occurs and does not use chmod or chown...

Comment: Do you have any cronjobs running that might change the permissions?

Comment: Not as far as I know... the only Cron job I made after a fresh install was one that prods my DNS update to work...

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions on how you would begin to debug this?

Comment: I would run `grep sshd /var/log/auth.log | tail` and see if there are any error messages about a public key not being accepted. (Replace `tail` with `less` to get scrollable full output if `tail` doesn't reveal anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved.

It was not an issue with SSH, nor the config tutorials but rather an incorrect diagnosis of the problem.

It turns out the SSH access issue did occur on a 24-48 hour basis, but looking back, this was only because 1) someone unplugged it, 2) we had a power-cut 3) I rebooted after a big update.

The common denominator being that **I restarted the server**, meaning when I was not logged in, my home directory remained encrypted and my authorized keys were not registering. Doh... what a noob.

So it was a red herring. The solution (moving the auth keys file out of the encrypted home directory) can be found in the wonderful [Ubuntu ssh guide - troubleshooting section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)